# Python Hangman problem with function for printing "_ a _ _ e _"

Tags: python

I am programming a small hangman game and I have kinda no Idea how I should resume my program. I have the part of the program which is giving me a list of the letters which are guessed correctly. My problem is that I don't know how to write the part where if I have a list with the known letters = [a, e] and the word "Banner", that it prints me a good user output which is using known letters and the word. Something like that: (known_letters and the word): "_ a _ _ e _". Do you have any ideas on how I can write this function efficiently? Thank you for your answers (:

```
word = "Banner"
known_letters = ["a", "e"]
def print__(word, letter):
  print(word, letter)
  for letters in word:
    if letter in word:
      #I have no Idea how to resume ):
#Output should be something like _ a _ _ e r.
```

Comment: Assuming that this is a regular game of hangman, if someone guessed `a` and the word is `banana`, you'd expect to see `_a_a_a`, correct? Not just one `a` revealed, but all of them?

Comment: yea correct. it is just a regular hangman game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some of the parts you need already there, a `for`-loop and some condition checking if a letter is `in` the word.

Here's a nice way to put that together:

```
word = "Banner"
known_letters = ["a", "e"]
to_print = ''.join(letter if letter in known_letters else '_' for letter in word)
print(to_print)
```

Or if you want spaces inbetween:

```
to_print = ' '.join(letter if letter in known_letters else '_' for letter in word)
```

These work because `str.join()` takes some iterable of strings and joins them together with the string it is called on, i.e. `'-'.join('a', 'b', 'c')` returns `'a-b-c'`.

And `letter if letter in known_letters else '_'` evaluates to the value of `letter` if `letter` is `in known_letters` and it evaluates to `'_'` otherwise.

So, doing that for all letters in `word`, gets you all the characters which can then be joined together (with empty strings, or spaces).

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "Banner"
known_letters = ["a", "e"]
def print__(word, letter):
    print(word, letter)
    answer=""
    for letters in word:
        if letters in known_letters:
            answer+=letters+" "
        else:
            answer+="_ "
    return answer
  
x=print__(word,known_letters)
print(x)
```